# Custom RIA Domain Service not based on an ADO.NET entity

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria, domain-service-class

All of my data can be accessed only through a COM object created like so:

```
Interaction.CreateObject("MyObject.Application","RemoteServer");
```

I have a bunch of APIs that I can use to query this object.  I have very little experience in RIA/Silverlight/Entity Models and I am wondering what the best way (or usual way) to go about "wrapping" this object, making it queryable, and putting it into a domain service would be!

I would love any tips!  Any direction would be better than what I have now!

Thanks!

Edit: I guess it will be:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(...);
//I will have to figure out how to get the remote server part to work...
```

Edit 2: Some more details: I am pulling back documents that look essentially like so:

```
InvoiceNo              | string
CompanyNumber          | string
CompanyName            | string
Date                   | datetime
DocumentDescription    | string
UserID                 | string
```

I am pulling them back from `MyObject.Application` so that I can compare them, for each date, to documents from our SQL Server database (which is simple to set up RIA for).

I have the methods to login/find/modify/delete (which should never happen) documents from `MyObject.Application` and am able to execute them... So it's just how to set up the wrapper class/DomainService/etc....  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your data services work with particular types of object. You will need data objects to hold that "shape" of data and add various attributes. The only required requirement is a property with a [key] attribute so that instances of your objects can be uniquely identified.

To make it work with RIA Services you need to create CRUD methods for each object type.
There are a few common variant possible on the methods names (change vs update etc), and you have [Create], [Read], [Update] & [Delete] attributes if you want to break the standard altogether.

The various methods are called automatically by RIA Services, so all you have to do is worry about the add of 1 object, the delete of 1 object, the update of 1 object, or returning an IQuerable (or at least an IEnumerable) of your object in the read method. You implement the actual storage any way you like.

*If you post more detail about you objects I can post a specific example.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I added some more detail.  I will be reading up on creating these data objects w/CRUD but I would love if you could post some sort of example!  It would help a lot... :-)